# Running DNSClient.Net on a C# Razor Page

Tags: c#, razor-pages

I am new to coding, but do okay at reusing code.
I just can't find a good example of running code on a razor page and displaying the info.

Here is the code I want to run on a razor webpage:

```
enter code here
```

@page "/revdns"
@inject DnsClient

## Reverse DNS Checker

This where we will display the DNS records..

@record

@ip

@code {

```
string lookup = new LookupClient();
string result = await lookup.QueryAsync("google.com", QueryType.A);

string record = result.Answers.ARecords().FirstOrDefault();
string ip = record?.Address;
```

}

Hopefully someone can help

**I have now tweaked the code**

I am new to coding, hoping you can help. I am getting the following errors.

Error   CS0103  The name 'QueryType' does not exist in the current context

Error   CS0103  The name 'record' does not exist in the current context

@page "/dnsquery"

## DNS Query

This where we will display the DNS records..

Record: @Record

IP Address: @Ip

@code {

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    
    var lookup = new DnsClient.LookupClient();
    var result = await DnsClient.LookupClient.QueryAsync("google.com", QueryType.A);
    Record = result.Answers.ARecords().FirstOrDefault();
    Ip = record?.Address;
}

string Record = "Loading...";
string Ip = "Loading...";
```

}

Comment: 'Console.WriteLine' will not be shown on the client, you should create HTML instead.

Comment: This is still not right as there are a number of errors.

`Code
@page "/revdns"


<h1>Reverse DNS Checker</h1>

@*// foreach(var nsRecord in result.Answers.NsRecords())
    // @DnsClient.Protocol.NsRecord*@

<p>This is the value in lookup: @lookup</p>
<p>This is the value in result: @result</p>
<p>Value of WriteRecord: @WriteRecord</p>

@code {

    var lookup = new LookupClient();
    var result = await lookup.QueryAsync("google.com", QueryType.A);

    foreach(var nsRecord in result.Answers.NsRecords())
    {
<p>WriteRecord(nsRecord.NSDName);</p>
        }
}`

Comment: looks like commenting doesn't allow code to be added, at least not nicely

Comment: You should EDIT your question and include the code formatted.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the 'async' keyword in a field declaration - you probably want to do the actual lookup in one of the lifecycle methods (example using OnInitialized for simplicity - look into OnAfterRender too)

Note, not addressing what LookupClient is or why you are injecting DnsClient...

```
@page "/revdns" 
@inject DnsClient

Reverse DNS Checker
This where we will display the DNS records..

@Record

@Ip

@code {

     protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync(){
        string lookup = new LookupClient();
        string result = await lookup.QueryAsync("google.com", QueryType.A);
        Record = result.Answers.ARecords().FirstOrDefault();
        Ip = record?.Address;
     }

    string Record = "Loading...";
    string Ip = "Loading...";
}
```

Comment: thanks for the code snippet, the only error was the inject line so I removed it.
Ran the project but it produced nothing on the screen.
So I closed and reopened VisualStudio, a lot more errors appeared almost for each line.

Error CS0118 'DnsClient' is a namespace but is used like a type BlazorWebAssembly 
Error  The 'inject' directive expects an identifier. BlazorWebAssembly 
Error CS0103 The name 'record' does not exist in the current context 
Plus  a number more

The reason I am using @inject DnsClient is that I have added this dependency
https://dnsclient.michaco.net/

Comment: @David - Okay so take away the inject line - you don't even use it anyway. The 'record does not exist' is probably because you have Record in one place and record in another (c# is case SENSETIVE)

Comment: now without the inject line, I get these errors

Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'LookupClient' could not be found 
Error CS1061 'string' does not contain a definition for 'QueryAsync' and no accessible extension method 'QueryAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found
Error CS0103 The name 'QueryType' does not exist in the current context 
Error CS1061 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Answers' and no accessible extension method 'Answers' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found

This is what made me think I need the inject line

Comment: @David - Not being cheeky, but you need to go do a beginners tutorial. There are many good ones (https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/CSharp-Fundamentals-for-Absolute-Beginners) or (https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/csharp) instead of just posting your errors without trying to fix them yourself. Otherwise you will not learn. 'Type or Namespace not found' is a very simple error, you need to read about 'References' and 'Imports'. The others I think are typos your code doesn't match what I posted exactly, otherwise you could not get those errors

Comment: Thanks for the references.
As I mentioned in my first line, I am a beginner but do okay with reusing code.
Once I get one working adding more pages and features will be easier.

I will see how I go, otherwise I may reach out on freelancer or one of those pay for service sites.

I would only think you are being cheeky if I didn't know where my current limitations are.  Thanks for your help, it is very much appreciated.

Comment: I built a basic windows app that enters some data into registry and then reads it out.
Learnt a lot, Alt Enter helped me get a handle on it. For some reason that doesn't work on my razor pages.

I am now down to two errors on this code:
Error CS0117 'LookupClient' does not contain a definition for 'QueryType' 
Error CS0103 The name 'record' does not exist in the current context 

Still working on it.

Thanks again for your help @Milney